# i need to implement solr schema with frequently updated field

Tags: lucene, solr, digg

I'm using Lucene/solr for searching and navigation in file upload application 
i need to update the indexed value 'downloaded' for each document for each download.

the same case happed in digg.com , they have how many "diggs" for each link while u searching

does i have to delete/insert new document for each download.
or there something which is better?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_update_a_specific_field_of_an_existing_document.3F) on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/), you cannot partially update a document:

> In Lucene to update a document the operation is really a delete followed by an add. You will need to add the complete document as there is no such "update only a field" semantics in Lucene.

You have to add the whole document if you wish to update a field.

Comment: i know that , there are no update implementation..
it's not my question . 

my question is how digg is implement it , and what's the best practice to implement the same idea digg

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. If Digg are storing the vote counts in Lucene at all, I imagine it would not be realtime. I would think a better way would be to store the votes in your primary store and cache it in Memcache for the view.

Comment: Ok, but each time someone vote for a url it's must be indexed in the lucene engine, so it become available for the search , and u can order your search results using the vote field

Comment: If it's available as a search field (for ordering or otherwise), yes, the document must be indexed. Unless indexing is rather fast, this index is probably updated on a delay. (i.e. scan for posts every minute which have changed and reindex them).